# 'Work on the remote' or 'work remotely'?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

What is the best way to name a kind of work when you do your job from home? (For example, I want to write an essay about it.)

Comment: `work remotely` and `working remotely` are used commonly, and so is `telecommuting`. See https://www.lifewire.com/what-should-we-call-people-who-work-remotely-2377987 for a discussion of neologisms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use the second version of the phrase.

> I work remotely.

Here, *remotely* is an adverb and the sentence means that you are working away from the office (or away from wherever the main work site actually is).

> I work on the remote.

Here, *remote* is a noun and the sentence means that you are working on something like a remote control—most likely repairing it or figuring out how to program it.